What is this cap on sink's drain tee for washer?
My pre-war apt has a washer/dryer in the kitchen, next to the dishwasher. The dishwasher drains into the usual port on the side of the sink's disposal, while the washer-dryer drains into this capped tee on top of the trap. Is this some sort of AAV or is it just a weird cap?



Looks like a diaphragm vent --I forget the proper name.

I was wondering if it was an AAV, but I think it is on the wrong side of the trap (it is upstream of the trap) for a vent. Is it just a weird cleanout cap?

it looks like a waste-pipe connector with a brass disc fitted in it.  -  So yes, a weird cap.
